# I can't figure out where there is an error in my program in the line basic.setLayout(new BoxLa

Tags: java

```
JPanel    basic=new   JPanel();

basic     setLayout(new BoxLayout(basic,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


add(basic);
```

Comment: you forgot the point (.) instead use this `basic.setLayout(new BoxLayout(basic,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`

Comment: am sory i forgot to write exactly how my code was: basic.setLayout(new BoxLayout(basic ,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code making correction. But waiting for peer review.

```
basic.setLayout(new BoxLayout(basic,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

update: YCF_L already answered it.